# Does it make sense to re-throwing exception in catch block?

Tags: java, exception

Does it make sense to throw exception from catch block just to log the message so that we are sure that what is causing the exception?

**Code**

```
  public void saveLogs(Logs logs) throws RemoteException
  {
        try
        {
            LogsOps.saveLogs(logs);
        }
        catch (RemoteException e)
        {
            log.info("RemoteException is thrown while trying to save logs ", e);
            throw new RemoteException("RemoteException caused while trying to save", e);
        }
    }
```

In response to one of the comments below that this method would throw StackOverFlow Exception, here the actual implementation of log.info which just displays those errors.

```
     /** Log the message and the exception with a level of INFO.
     * @param message - The message text.
     * @param t - An exception to display.
     */
    public void info(Object message, Throwable t)
    {
        String nullSafeMessage = (message != null) ? message.toString() : t.getClass().getSimpleName();
        log.info(nullSafeMessage, t);
    }
```

So there never would be Stackoverflow exception thrown.

Comment: Wouldn't the stacktrace contain the origin and the message should be as descriptive as possible to avoid this. But I have see it done, rarely. Unless nothing else is going to log it.

Comment: You're actually logging exception thrown to logging? That would be StackOverFlow Exception!

Comment: @TejaswiRana: I do not see it throwing StackOverFlow Exception, why do you thing that it would throw Stack Over Flow exception?, see my updated question.

Comment: It won't if LogOps.saveLogs(logs) does in fact throw RemoteException it is caught. Just curious though ->  Your Logs in SaveLogs and logging in log.info are two different things? Looks to me like they're the same thing and log.info does not actually write but then is saved to a collection of Logs which is then saved at certain interval.

Comment: log.info is standard logger that we are using and save logs is page in application which captures details about parsing logs for each parsing job request, hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on what's going to catch the exception higher up. If nothing *else* is going to log the message, then sure, it makes sense - although I'd probably rethrow the *original* exception instead of creating a new one:

```
catch (RemoteException e)
{
    log.info("RemoteException is thrown while trying to save logs ", e);
    throw e;
}
```

Ideally, though, you'd have a single `catch` block higher up the stack, which would log appropriately - if you're *just* logging the exception, that can get all the information anyway.

It *may* make sense to catch/log/rethrow when you want to log information which *isn't* present in the exception, such as parameter values.

Comment: Agree, but in my case, I am capturing exception higher up with generic log message but i want to capture specific message as to why and when current RemoteException is thrown so that it would be easier from debugging application point of view when we have some issues with it.

Comment: @Rachel Any damn logger I know prints method names and class names so you don't need specific information. Also you can use `Exception.getMesssage` if you only want to print message and move on.

Answer (score 3):

Presuming that you will eventually handle the propagated exception, this tactic of catch-log-rethrow just clutters up the log file. Imagine that this is done the entire way up the stacktrace - you end up with reams of redundant error information that serves no useful purpose.

If you are not handling the exception you shouldn't log it either.

Answer (score 0):

Besides for logging, this approach may also be used to perform necessary cleanup in case of a failure before returning control to a caller further up the stack.

For example

```
InputStream is = new InputStream( ... )

try {

    is.read(...);

    return is;

} catch ( IOException ioe ) {
    is.close();
    throw ioe;
}
```

This is, of course, a somewhat special use which can be avoided elegantly most of the time by using a `finally` clause - but not always, as the case above demonstrates.